# Renaming a batch of folders to follow a certain pattern

Tags: bash, powershell, rename

so I have a bunch of folders that are numbered like `1, 2, 3, 4, 5... 150`. I would like to change the names of these folders to follow a 3 digit pattern, so instead they become `001, 002, 003, 004,.. 050, 051.. 150`. However I'm not the best at Bash or Powershell, so I'm having some difficulty doing it myself. I'm fine with using either since I can use PS or WSL to accomplish the task. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PowerShell ( executed from parent folder ):

Verbose:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory |
   Where-Object Name -match '^\d{1,2}$' |
      Rename-Item -NewName { '{0:d3}' -f [Int]$_.Name }
```

KeyBanger:

```
gci -ad | ? Name -match '^\d{1,2}$' | ren -New { '{0:d3}' -f [Int]$_.Name }
```

Alternate `-NewName` ScriptBlock:

```
{ $_.Name.PadLeft(3,'0') }
```

Comment: the pattern should be '^\d{1,3}$' in order to match the numbers from 100 to 150, no?

Comment: You only need tot pad one & two digit folder names. 100 - 150 don't need to be padded. If you try to rename an item to its current name you get a `Destination must be different than Source` error.

Comment: Worked great, thank you.

Comment: You're selcome.

Answer (score 1):

Try this powershell code:

```
# Set the location to the directory where folders are, replace "Filepath" with original
Set-Location "Filepath"
# Get a list of items, filter out the directories using a Regex that filters the directories with digits at beginning 
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {($_.PSIsContainer) -and ($_.Basename -match "^[0-9]+")} | ForEach {
  # Get the name without extension in Integer data type and pad leading zeros with format string, ToString will also work
  $n = [int]($_.BaseName)
  $e = '{0:d3}"' -f $n
   # Rename each folders
  Rename-Item -Path "$_.Fullname" -Newname "$e"
}
```